# Ruby On Rails Better way to get count of records with date ranges

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have written code for a chart wherein data is retrieved by date ranges. I have a `period_start` and `period_end` which is just the entire chart range. I also have a `period_offset` which can be 30 minutes, 1 hour, 1 week, etc.. The implementation I made makes incremental ranges where I get the count of records where its `created_at` and `confirmed_at` column falls in the current date range being iterated on. What's returned are two arrays containing the counts for `created_at` and `confirmed_at`

```
      temp_period_start = period_start
      while temp_period_start < period_end
        temp_period_end = temp_period_start + period_offset
        graph_data_created << recs.actions_dated('created_at', temp_period_start, temp_period_end).size
        graph_data_confirmed << recs.confirmed.actions_dated('confirmed_at', temp_period_start, temp_period_end).size
        temp_period_start = temp_period_end
      end
```

`actions_dated` is a just model scope defined as:

```
scope :actions_dated, lambda { |col, ps, pe|
    condition_str = "%s >= ? and %s < ?"
    condition = condition_str % [col, col]
    where(condition, ps, pe)
}
```

While `.confirmed` is another scope but is dependent on a parent association (i.e. `rec belongs_to :rec_parent`

```
scope :confirmed, -> { joins(:rec_parent)
    .where("rec_parent.start_flag = 1 OR
           (rec_parent.start_flag = 0 AND rec.confirmed_at IS NOT NULL)")}
```

**The Problem**

This was tested on an environment with at least 50k instances of rec. The dashboard page ended up not being displayed and returning a 504 error. I figured that the snippet above causes the significant slowdowns leading to the timeout.

I looked into [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/) but unfortunately our database doesn't have the Timezone support that the gem needs so it won't work.

What's the best way to refactor the code above to get the needed data. I haven't dabbled much in the performance aspect of queries so I'm not that well-versed. TIA!

Comment: Take the query and run it with `EXPLAIN` in your mysql query browser (whatever it is called these days), there you can see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the tables, a more useful example of the models, the data and the expected result? Knowing which database you're using would also be very helpful. Basically to create a BETWEEN query you just pass a range to `where`. `where(created_at: 5.years.ago..1.year.ago)`. To group by an interval you would use `.group( DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at))`  on Postgres, other RDBMS:es have different date functions. If you want to select a count per group and get the result as an array you can use `.pluck('COUNT(column_name), COUNT(other_column_name)')`.